# First Order Logic recast as an Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, first-order-logic

I'm wondering if someone can offer an intuition of what is meant when mathematicians talk of recasting first-order logic statements as algebraic expressions. e.g. Halmos, Barnes, or Mack?

Here is a simple example to illustrate this question, adapted from [forall x: Calgary](https://forallx.openlogicproject.org/).

If we had two variables "lover" and "loved" that ranged over the domain {"Imre", "Juan", "Karl"}, and a predicate $L$ (for Lovers) which was true for the following values of lover and loved.

| lover | loved |
| --- | --- |
| Imre | Juan |
| Juan | Karl |
| Imre | Karl |
| Karl | Imre |

then it is true that everyone loves someone $\forall lover \exists loved  L(lover, loved)$

If we had an algebraization of FOL:

1. Would we have defined a set closed under some list of operators?
2. Could such an algebraization read like one of these two forms?

- $forall(exists(variable(loved, variable(lover,L(lover,loved)))))$
- $L(lover,loved).variable(lover).variable(loved).exists().forall()$

Or is an algebraization of FOL something else?

Thanks

David

Comment: If you want us to comment on statements made by Halmos, Barnes or Mack, then please give references to those statements.

Comment: Are you familiar with the relationship between Boolean algebra and propositional logic? The search for a good algebraization of first-order logic is motivated by that.

Comment: Thanks, @RobArthan, I am reaching for an intuition of a school of thought, rather than a reflection on specific statements. 

My question assumes that the idea of "algebraization of FOL" is a body of endeavor about which one could develop an intuition.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, yes I'm familiar with the relationship between Boolean algebra and propositional logic, and have a clear intuition for the set which is closed under boolean operators.  

I'm curious to have an intuition of how one may extend this to FOL. I'm looking for a definition of a set that is closed under some set of operators that is sufficient to encode FOL, but perhaps "algebraic logic" is on a different quest.

Comment: OK then here's the rough "cylindrical algebra" story. Given a language $L$ and a set of variables $X$, let $F_{L,X}$ be the set of formulas built from those symbols via Booleans and quantifiers as usual using only the variables from $X$. This set is equipped with some natural operations, namely the usual Booleans *and* the quantifiers $\forall x$ for each $x\in X$ (we don't need the separate existential quantifiers since we can build those from $\forall$ and negation). This is analogous to the Boolean algebra of wffs formed from some set of propositional atoms, but it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: That is, the "set that is closed under some set of operators" is the set of all FOL formulas in the appropriate language/variables, and the operators in question are the Booleans and the (variable-specific) quantifiers. But this is only one approach; there are others.

Comment: I am sorry but it is quite unsatisfactory not to give specific references. As far as I know the "school of thought" you refer to is a figment of your imagination. Please ground your question in the literature. And yes, the close vote is from me.

Comment: You may be interested in Halmos' [*An autobiography of polyadic algebras*](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=f2693ca54467330231a9be81a094a694f3b942fb). I don't agree with everything Halmos says - in particular, my own aesthetics are much different from his - but he does a good job I think of explaining his mindset.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks for this.  Beautiful. Reading this filled me with a lightness of heart to find another spirit who has been "stumbling painfully from one blind alley to the next"! I have an intuition that there /is/must be/should be/ a straightforward and user-friendly way of algebraically expressing quantifiers as a set of values that is closed under a small list of operations.  The set here is a set of values rather than the set of all FOL formulas. I have a sketch of a candidate algebra that might fill this void and would be happy to share it if anyone else is interested in such a goal.